# Scrape text in SPAN array for div ID using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer, scrape

I have this HTML:

```html
<div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMiddle_cphCenterColumn_uctDiveInfoDisplay_TabContainer1_tabScubeCoursesOffered_ScubaCoursesViewDIV" class="modules-wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div>  <span> -Master Scuba Diver </span> </div></td>
      <td><div>  <span> -Fish Identification </span> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>  <span> -Underwater Navigator </span> </div></td>
      <td><div>  <span> -EFR Primary Care with AED </span> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>  <span> -Search & Recovery Diver </span> </div></td>
      <td><div>  <span> -Deep Diver </span> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>  <span> -Wreck Diver </span> </div></td>
      <td><div>  <span> -Divemaster </span> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>  <span> -AWARE Coral Reef Conservation </span> </div></td>
      <td><div>  <span> -PADI Seal Team </span> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>  <span> -Bubblemaker </span> </div></td>
      <td><div>  <span> -Advanced Open Water Diver </span> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>  <span> -Peak Performance Buoyancy Diver </span> </div></td>
      <td><div>  <span> -Scuba Diver </span> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>  <span> -Rescue Diver </span> </div></td>
      <td><div>  <span> -Discover Scuba Diving </span> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>  <span> -PADI Master Seal Team </span> </div></td>
      <td><div>  <span> -Project Aware </span> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>  <span> -Open Water Diver </span> </div></td>
      <td><div>  <span> -Adventure Diver </span> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>  <span> -Skin Diver </span> </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to get the text inside each SPAN for the DIV with that ID and return each text element as an array, how do I achieve this? I have tried everything...

Comment: I dont know anything about puppeteer, but it seems like, you could use document.evaluate, what allows you to use XPath expression to find DOM nodes you need.

Comment: Can update the question with an example of "have tried everything"? At least the latest try.

Comment: @theDavidBarton When I said everything I meant: getElementById on the DIV ID, but that didn't work; I tried $$eval as well like your solution before but I didn;t think to map the inner text of a span, was just using getElementByID with .textContent...loads of solutions cause I am just not sure of the syntax with Pupeteer

Answer (score 4):

The easiest one-liner solution is to use [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.1.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) to collect all `<span>` elements in the page context - it runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` in the background. As it returns an array of elements you are able to iterate them over with `Array.map` to get the `innerText` of each in the end.

```js
const spanTexts = await page.$$eval('span', elements => elements.map(el => el.innerText))
console.log(spanTexts)
```

Within a specific `<div>` you can create a wildcard between the `#id-name` and the `span` element with a Universal selector (`*`). You can read more about how to create CSS selectors yourself [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

```js
const spanTexts = await page.$$eval('#ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMiddle_cphCenterColumn_uctDiveInfoDisplay_TabContainer1_tabScubeCoursesOffered_ScubaCoursesViewDIV * span', elements => elements.map(el => el.innerText))
console.log(spanTexts)
```

Comment: Great answer man! This works at getting every SPAN element... but what if i want only the SPAN elements in the DIV with this id (can I evaluate on a specific ID for a span... what things can i put in the  ' ' quotation marks?): "ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMiddle_cphCenterColumn_uctDiveInfoDisplay_TabContainer1_tabScubeCoursesOffered_ScubaCoursesViewDIV"

Comment: OK, it will ruin the "one-liner" because of the long element ID , but you are able to select every span inside the specific div with the id if you put a `*` between the id and the span element like this: `'#ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMiddle_cphCenterColumn_uctDiveInfoDisplay_TabContainer1_tabScubeCoursesOffered_ScubaCoursesViewDIV * span'`. Asterisk in a CSS selector means a wildcard which selects all elements within that order of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to get the specific ID and then get the text in the spans

```
const spanTexts = await page.$$eval('#ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMiddle_cphCenterColumn_uctDiveInfoDisplay_TabContainer1_tabScubeCoursesOffered_ScubaCoursesViewDIV span', elements => elements.map(el => el.innerText))
```

Thanks a lot @thedavidbarton